# Why was my question closed?

Tags: discussion, specific-question, moderation

I don't usually have any issue with stack exchange moderators, but in this situation I really don't understand why [my question](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/q/27630/26000) was closed. The reason listed is "unclear what you are asking," but the question is clearly stated. Why was my question closed?

Answer (score 1):

What university does the claim apply to? Or country? Or...

Your question can have many answers, all valid; you need to specify it. It's too broad.

I did add a comment. I guess "this applies... Where?" was too synthetic. My bad.

Answer (score 0):

The closure shouldn't be **unclear what you're asking**, but instead it should or could be **too broad** because it is clear what you're asking.

In this case, the moderator's intervention was a bit inappropriate, especially that your question has been answered.

However, the moderator has a point: Your question ("claim") could apply to too many universities and universities in different countries, that would nominate your question for being too board.

Comment: I used "unclear" assuming that the question is actually specific to a context, but the OP did not include it. If the OP really intended to refer to any possible university, then yep, it would be too broad.